# As on element animates in, animate another out

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

As one element slides in I need the other element to slide out. At the moment I have set it to fadeOut. This is the code I have so far:

```
$('#contact').click(function () {
    $('#contact-info').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $('#work-menu').fadeOut('100');
});
$('#menu').click(function () {
    $('#work-menu').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $('#contact-info').fadeOut('100');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/v2bN9/1/)

How can I change this code to make the opposite elements slide back as the other one slides into view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `'hide'`

```
$('#contact').click(function () {
    $('#contact-info').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $('#work-menu').animate({
        width: 'hide'
    });
});
$('#menu').click(function () {
    $('#work-menu').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    $('#contact-info').animate({
        width: 'hide'
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/v2bN9/5/)

Answer (score 1):

By checking if its `:visible` you can do this way:

```
$('#contact').click(function () {
    $('#contact-info').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    if ($("#work-menu").is(":visible"))
        $('#work-menu').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
});
$('#menu').click(function () {
    $('#work-menu').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
    if ($("#contact-info").is(":visible"))
        $('#contact-info').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2bN9/7/)